# How to remove 'Remind Me' button from CallKit UI?

Tags: ios, ios10, callkit

I'm using iOS 10's CallKit in my app to receive incoming calls. I am using **CXHandleType: CXHandleTypeGeneric** with specific caller handle.

**1-** I am not able to get that in **point 2**, where from string **'Audio...'** is coming? I have only set string 'Call From' in CXProviderConfiguration.

```
CXProviderConfiguration *configuration = [[CXProviderConfiguration alloc] initWithLocalizedName:@"Call From"];
```

I want to remove this **'Audio...'** string, please help.

**2-** When CallKit UI is open on receive call then an option 'Remind Me' button is also present.
How can I remove it from this native UI? As per my requirement this button is useless.

Please help, thanks in advance.

I have configure call kit:

```
- (void)configureCallKit {
    CXProviderConfiguration *configuration = [[CXProviderConfiguration alloc] initWithLocalizedName:@"Call From"];
    configuration.maximumCallGroups = 1;
    configuration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1;
    UIImage *callkitIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iconMask80"];
    configuration.iconTemplateImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(callkitIcon);

    _callKitProvider = [[CXProvider alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration];
    [_callKitProvider setDelegate:self queue:nil];

    _callKitCallController = [[CXCallController alloc] init];
}
```

[image]

Comment: is audio your app name? It is not currently possible to disable this button in the native incoming call UI or change it to use your app instead.

Comment: No, Audio is not my app name. I have also searched but there is no audio string in my code.

Comment: If we cannot disable remind me button then how can i use it without remind me button? Please suggest.

Comment: @AsifRaza did u manage to remove this remind me button?

Answer (score 1):

For question number 1:

When you create the configuration, you pass "Call From" instead app name, so Callkit shows you "Call from Audio" instead "AppName Audio".

For solve it you can create provider configuration as:

```
CXProviderConfiguration * configuration = [[CXProviderConfiguration alloc] [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]];
```

For second question, I would like remove it too, but I don't know how and if it could be remove.

Comment: I want to remove Audio, please check question.

Comment: You cant do it. Apple use it for identify if the calle os audio or video.

Comment: Yes, I already got it that when user got call connected then it gives audio timer when I removed string "Call From" it shows Audio XX:XX:XX. Thanks.